# Why is $scope applied to some expressions but not others?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in a controller:

```
$scope.address = new Address();
$scope.hasAddress = $scope.address.street !== undefined && $scope.address.street.length > 0;
```

And this markup:

```
<p>{{address.street !== undefined && address.street.length > 0}}</p>
<p>{{hasAddress}}</p>
```

And then this, indirectly through some includes:

```
<input type="text" ... ng-model="address.street" required>
```

When the input first appears, the street is undefined, so the rendered html says:

```
<p>false</p><p>false</p>
```

as expected.  But when I enter characters into the input, the html is rendered as:

```
<p>true</p><p>false</p>
```

Why doesn't the hasAddress variable update?  It's changed indirectly by the address object.  Is this a case where I use $scope.$apply()?  (and oh no, a new thing where I don't know what the heck I'm doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because nothing in your JS is telling it to update.

Add to your input: `ng-change="updateVar()"`, then in your JavaScript:

```
$scope.updateVar = function() {
  $scope.hasAddress = $scope.address.street !== undefined && $scope.address.street.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, brilliant.  Thanks.  But can you help me understand in general?  Aren't the two <p>'s just two expressions that depend on objects, one more indirectly than the other?  I would have guessed that angular understands the second-order dependency, i.e. expression 1 depends on the address object, expression 2 depends on a scope variable that depends on the address object.

Comment: No the controller only runs once, to have it do things you have to have events. I added an event to the input, and then had it trigger the function shown.